# Dupe text should change to reflect that a question has multiple duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

The current text is:

> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.

But in reality, it is an duplicate of multiple question**s**.

Should this copy be changed?

[image: 5 Duplicates]

Comment: How whould you choose which dupes to display?  Eg. Java NullPointerException and C 'i++ + ++i' sequence point questions have hundreds of duplicates.